# Can I add a bottom padding to iOS UINavigationBar to alter the visual height of the bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I’m implementing a design that requires the navigation bar to visually appear to be 64px tall (even though the content fits inside the standard height). The standard **UINavigationBar** height on iOS is 44px and it is strongly discouraged try to to change the that (see: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/88202?answerId=274620022#274620022).

So, what I’m trying to do instead is to add a padding of 10px both above and below the bar itself, but I can’t figure out if this is even possible.

I am able to extend the bar by 20px by setting the **UINavigationController’s** `additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 20`, but the bottom of the navigation bar is still flush with the bottom of the navigation controller, and I need it to be -10px from bottom.

So, my question, is this possible, or am I chasing a ghost here?

**EDIT**: To clarify, I want it to look like how the navigation bar looks in the iMessage conversation view, i.e. a tall navigation bar, but with vertically centered content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a customized navigation bar to solve this issue.
Because built-in UI is not easier to adjust or customize. I have tried many tricks but they didn't work.

I already made a base screen that automatically adds a navigation bar on top, just need to set left/right button and the label. This navigation bar is just a normal `UIView`.

Comment: Yes, that't pretty much the conclusion I have come to as well. But I'm still thinking about what would be the best way to integrate this on all views. Adding it to the navigation controller or the view controllers.